# Increase Google Map API request limit

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I came across the Google maps API, and am trying to use the places API. The documentation says that there is limit of 2500 requests per day for app using it in play store. 2500 per day is insufficient for my needs. Is there a way to increase the limit?

Comment: because google is not NGO.

Comment: Pay $10.000 and you will have 100.000 limitation per day ^^.
Follow [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/licensing)

Comment: Read the usage guide, 
https://developers.google.com/places/android/usage
Pay more, get more.